# Importing Google maps doesn't show in blender

Tags: modeling

I installed blender 3.4 with maps modelimporter v6.2 and renderdoc 1.25. but whenever I import rdc file it doesn't appear in the screen ,nor it displays any error. I have followed everything from YouTube on how to import Google maps but on importing the file nothing appears.

Comment: Both your "modelimporter" and "renderdoc 1.25" appear to be external programs or addons and are not part of Blender so question about them are off-topic here. Suggest you ask on the web site(s) where you found them.